# Frontpage Slideshow not working in firefox

Tags: php, css, joomla

Does anybody no why the front page slide show joomla component would not work in firefox on this site

http://east-belfast.wsini.com/

Comment: which version of FF are u using Its working on 10.0.1

Comment: version 12.0 I am using of firefox

Comment: works fine for me in Firefox 13 beta 1, however during each image transition, I see this text:

"Frontpage SlideShow is the most eye-catching way to display your featured articles, stories or even products in your Joomla! based…"

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a Javascript conflict, because there is running Mootools and JQuery side by side, not the best combination! Seen this problem a couple times by my own scripts in Joomla. You could try the Jquery includer plugin, it claims to solve any javascript problems: http://bit.ly/aQ5tap

Hope it works for you!